# Which configuration leads to Invalid beta parameter: 1.1203716642316337 - should be in [0.0, 1.0) error?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, hyperparameters, ray, ray-tune

I am running a hyperparameter tuning using Ray Tune integration (1.9.2) and hugging face transformers framework (4.15.0).

This is the code that is responsible for the procedure (based on this [example](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/examples/pbt_transformers.html)):

```py
def search_hyper_parameters(
    trainer: Trainer, name: str = None, n_trials: int = 5
) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    def get_hp_boundaries(_trial):
        return {
            "adam_beta1": tune.uniform(0.0, 1.0),
            "adam_beta2": tune.uniform(0.0, 1.0),
            "learning_rate": tune.loguniform(1e-6, 1e-4),
            "num_train_epochs": tune.choice(list(range(3, 8))),
            "seed": tune.randint(1, 100),
            "per_device_train_batch_size": tune.choice([4, 8, 16, 32, 64]),
        }

    scheduler = PopulationBasedTraining(
        time_attr="training_iteration",
        metric="eval_accuracy",
        mode="max",
        perturbation_interval=1,
        hyperparam_mutations={
            "adam_beta1": tune.uniform(0.0, 1.0),
            "adam_beta2": tune.uniform(0.0, 1.0),
            "adam_epsilon": tune.choice([1e-8, 2e-8, 3e-8, 1e-9, 2e-9, 3e-10]),
            "weight_decay": tune.uniform(0.0, 0.3),
            "learning_rate": tune.uniform(1e-5, 5e-5),
            "max_grad_norm": tune.uniform(0.0, 1.0),
        },
    )

    reporter = CLIReporter(
        parameter_columns={
            "adam_epsilon": "adam_epsilon",
            "adam_beta1": "adam_beta1",
            "adam_beta2": "adam_beta2",
            "weight_decay": "w_decay",
            "seed": "seed",
            "learning_rate": "lr",
            "per_device_train_batch_size": "train_bs/gpu",
            "num_train_epochs": "num_epochs",
            "max_grad_norm": "max_grad_norm",
        },
        metric_columns=[
            "eval_accuracy",
            "eval_loss",
            "epoch",
            "training_iteration",
        ],
    )

    best_trial = trainer.hyperparameter_search(
        backend="ray",
        hp_space=get_hp_boundaries,
        direction="maximize",
        n_trials=n_trials,
        resources_per_trial={"cpu": 1, "gpu": 1},
        scheduler=scheduler,
        keep_checkpoints_num=1,
        checkpoint_score_attr="training_iteration",
        stop={"eval_accuracy": 0.98},
        progress_reporter=reporter,
        local_dir="~/ray_results/",
        name=name,
        log_to_file=True,
    )

    return best_trial.hyperparameters
```

Sometimes, the tuning fails due `Invalid beta parameter` error.

```py
File "/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 262, in run
  self._entrypoint()
File "/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 330, in entrypoint
  return self._trainable_func(self.config, self._status_reporter,
File "/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 597, in _trainable_func
  output = fn()
File "/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/integrations.py", line 282, in dynamic_modules_import_trainable
  return trainable(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/tune/utils/trainable.py", line 344, in inner
  trainable(config, **fn_kwargs)
File "/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/integrations.py", line 183, in _objective
  local_trainer.train(resume_from_checkpoint=checkpoint, trial=trial)
File "/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1181, in train
  self.create_optimizer_and_scheduler(num_training_steps=max_steps)
File "/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 801, in create_optimizer_and_scheduler
  self.create_optimizer()
File "/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 842, in create_optimizer
  self.optimizer = optimizer_cls(optimizer_grouped_parameters, **optimizer_kwargs)
File "/app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/optimization.py", line 306, in __init__
  raise ValueError(f"Invalid beta parameter: {betas[1]} - should be in [0.0, 1.0)")
```

I defined the hyperparameters boundaries for both adam_beta1 & adam_beta2 values.

Which configuration leads to this error?